# Bipartite graph has a vertex with all incident edges in some perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with a perfect matching. Prove that $G$ has a node $v$ for which
every edge incident to $v$ belongs to a perfect matching.

I don't think that this question is true if all the edges incident to $v$ belongs to the same perfect matching.

My attempt:
Suppose $v$ is not incident to any perfect matching of $G$. This implies that $G$ cannot have a perfect matching, which is a contradiction.

Am I on the right way, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @David, thank you for your comment. But I can't understand how the answer suggested for this problem is true because it is not complete.

Comment: Which part of the answer were you not able to understand? The first hint might not be understandable without the required background, but the 2nd does not require much prerequisite

Comment: @David, the last two lines of the 2nd one is not clear. How it forms a cycle?

Comment: I've expanded the hint to a complete answer. Does it answer your inquiry?

Answer (score 0):

I believed that the answer has been explained sufficiently by a previous post.

I will however expand on the explanation on some of the steps since there appears to still be some confusion.

Let $G=(U,V,E)$ be the bipartite graph, with $U$ and $V$ being the two partitions in the bipartite graph, and $E$ the edges. By supposition, a perfect matching exist in the graph.

- Let $M$ be some perfect matching.
- Take any vertex $v \in V$. Set $v_0 = v$. Assume it has an edge $\{v_0,u_0\}$ that does not belong to any perfect matching (otherwise you are done), where $u_0$ is the other vertex incident to that edge.
- Let $v_1$ be a neighbour of $u_0$ in $M$ (i.e. $u_0v_1\in M$).
- Now pick an edge of $\{v_1,u_1\}$ that does not belong to $M$. If this does not exist, this meant that $v_1$ has all its incident edges in a perfect matching and you are done.
- Therefore, you can repeat these steps to get a sequence $v_0,u_0,v_1,u_1,v_2,\ldots$ alternating between $V$ and $U$, and also edges between them alternating between $E \setminus M$ and $M$.
- Because the graph is finite, you will find $v_i = v_j$ (or $u_i = u_j$) for some $i < j$, and let $i$ and $j$ be the first such pair.
- Observe that you got an alternating cycle, which means the complement of the cycle (containing $\{v_0,u_0\}$), combined with the unused edges in $M$ is also a perfect matching and you are done.